# Serializing objects in a list with RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, poco, restsharp

I have a problem serializing my POCO objects to XML using RestSharp. My POCO object looks like this:

**Person**

```
[SerializeAs(Name = "person")]
public class Person
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "author-id")]
    public int? AuthorId { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "background")]
    public string Background { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "first-name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "last-name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "company-name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "contact-data")]
    public ContactData ContactData { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "tags")]
    public List<tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**ContactData**

```
public class ContactData
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "addresses")]
    public List<object> Addresses { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "phone-numbers")]
    public List<object> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "email-adresses")]
    public List<object> EmailAddresses { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "web-addresses")]
    public List<object> WebAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

**EmailAddress**

```
[SerializeAs(Name = "email-address")]
public class EmailAddress
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

This gives me the following XML when serialized:

```
<person>
    <first-name>my firstname</first-name> 
    <contact-data>
        <email-adresses>
            <EmailAddress>
                <address>my@email.com</address> 
                <location>Work</location> 
             </EmailAddress>
        </email-adresses>
    </contact-data>
    <tags>
        <tag>
            <name>Nyhedsbrev</name> 
        </tag>
    </tags>
</person>
```

As you might notice, the EmailAddress `SerializeAs` is ignored. I think this may be because it's in a `List` since the `Person` object is correctly serialized as `<person>`

I need my POCO objects within a List (or some collection) to be serialized using the annotation instead of the class name itself.

Has anyone found a workaround on this?

Answer (score 1):

Traced this to a bug in RestSharp. I forked the Git repository, fixed it and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/361).